# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing, After opening ASP.Net MVC project with visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP.net MVC project which uses meth to compose its parts. Everything was working fine until I opened the project with Visual Studio 2015. Then I received this error...

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I closed the project and opened back up in Visual Studio 2013 and tried to run. However now I received the same error in 2013, where it used to work before opening in 2015. Does anyone know the cause of this error and how to correct the problem??

Comment: You can upload your project to github and let me work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still am not sure why opening the project with Visual Studio 2015 caused this problem. I can only assume that opening in 2015 added code somewhere that referred to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing.DLL library.

Cause notwithstanding, to fix, I added Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing.DLL to the project references. Once I did that, everything worked fine again. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem occur in VS2013 today, and I finally solved it in exactly the same fashion, by adding a reference to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing'. In my case this occurred when switching project references from embedded interops to using the PIA assemblies directly. I could not find a setting that controlled this, but fuslogvw left no question as to the culprit.